# Is there something like python decorators for c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gree

I am wrapping calls to an API and most of my methods have in their first lines:

```
if ( !Gree.Authorizer.IsAuthorized() )
{
    return;
}
```

In python I would decorate those methods with something like `@login_required`.

What would you use to refactor that type of logic in `c#`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a subset of a more general programming methodology called Aspect Oriented Programming.

C# seems to support it through several libraries, and one can also roll out his own, thanks to some of the CLR features. See [Aspect Oriented Programming using .NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/3/) which covers its basic principles (I am linking the part of the article talking about the specifics of C#, but the rest is equally interesting if you are looking for ready-made solutions like PostSharp, as mentioned in another answer).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check if this works with `Unity3d`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any AOP tool for C# such as [this](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) one.

> With PostSharp, software developers can encapsulate implementation
>   patterns into classes called aspects, and apply these aspects to their
>   code using custom attributes.

Comment: PostSharp is a `.exe`. I want something to use it from `Unity3d` which uses Mono.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with python but it seems you are looking for "attributes" ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), (which are pretty similar to Java annotations).

In particular, .NET provides the "[AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)", which does exactly what you want (and maybe a little more). While you are not under .NET, this may still shed some light in the implementatino you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `attributes` are just meta data attached to class/method etc and they don't do anything themselves. You need to use another tool which read this meta data using reflection and do the required stuff which is what all AOP tools does